# Node.js async task queue implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Here is an async task queue implementation. The idea is to reuse node.js standard library as much as possible.

```
const { Readable, Writable } = require('stream');

const delay = (ms) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })

const task = (message) => {
  console.log(`${message} started`)

  return delay(500).then(() => message + ' solved')
}

class AsyncTaskQueue {
  constructor(limit = 7) {

    this.queue = new Readable({
      objectMode: true,
      read(size) {}
    })
    this.processor = new Writable({
      objectMode: true,
      highWaterMark: limit + 1,
      write(task, encoding, callback) {
        task().finally(() => callback())
      },
      writev(tasks, callback) {
        Promise.all(tasks.map(({chunk}) => chunk().catch(err => err)))
          .finally(() => callback())
      }
    });
    this.queue.pipe(this.processor)
  }

  addTask(execute) {
    const closure = { resolve: null, reject: null }
    const task = () => execute().then(closure.resolve).catch(closure.reject)
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      closure.resolve = resolve;
      closure.reject = reject;
    })
    this.queue.push(task)
    return promise
  } 
}

const q = new AsyncTaskQueue();

for (let i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
  q.addTask(
    task.bind(null, i)
  ).then(console.log)
```